# grid of cubes android opengles

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I read the dimensions of a cube from a file (x,y,z) and create opengl vertex array with equally spaced points. I am able to display the points as a 3d point cube of dimension (x,y,z). However, I want to display small cubes instead of points so that the output will look like a grid of cubes of dimension x*Y*Z instead of  3d points. How can I achieve this in android openges1.0 in java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an index buffer which lists the order of vertices (from your vertex buffer) to visit, and then draw them as triangles (or ideally a triangle strip).

For instance, if you have four vertices, top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right, in that order, your index buffer will be something like `[0, 1, 3, 2]` to wind the vertices clockwise.

Since the vertices are equally spaced and axis-aligned, it should not be too hard to write a loop which will generate the appropriate index buffer for you.

Comment: This method works..however, it does not fill the volume of the cube.I also need to slice the cube,, and if i do that, there will be empty spaces between 2 strips of traingle planes.